# A tool to search for certain moves played

Tags: software

Is there a tool to display how many times a certain move has been played?
Note that I do not mean openings, I mean specific moves. Moves that I am looking for would be castling with checkmate or underpromotion to a knight with checkmate, and similar things. Is there a tool available to search for something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chess Query Language](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/) operates on PGN files of games and does what you want as well as much more powerful stuff. It is a free download. There are lots of examples to get you started [here](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/examples.html).